# JQuery AJAX parsing data issue

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Something is going wrong with this logic. The issue happens very rarely though. This is written by someone else and has landed on my lap to code review. In the JSP we are using this JQuery routine:

```
var url = '<context_path>/customerservice/checkeligibility';
var type = "POST";
jQuery.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: type,
   dataType: 'html',
   complete: function(res, status) {
        var result = eval( '(' + res.responseText + ')' );
        var eligibilityMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.customerEligibilityMessage));
        if (result.displayEligibility) {
                jQuery('#eligibilitySection').show();
                if(eligibilitymsg!=null) {
                    jQuery('#eligibleDiv').show();
                    jQuery('#eligibilityMessage').append(eligibilityMessage);
                } else {
                    jQuery('#eligibleDiv').hide();
                }
        } else {
            jQuery('#eligibilitySection').hide();
        }
  }
```

Customer.java:

```
checkeligibility() {
    ..
    ..
    InstallmentData data = CustomerInstallmentData.getEligibility(request);

    if (data != null) {
        form.setDisplayEligibility(data.isDisplayEligibility());
        form.setCustomerEligibilityMessage(data.getCustomerEligibilityMessage());
    }

    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    values.put("displayEligibility", form.getDisplayEligibility());
    values.put("customerEligibilityMessage", form.getCustomerEligibilityMessage());

    JSONWriter.write(response.getWriter(), values, 2);
    ..
    ..
}
```

I wrote most of the text above by hand so there maybe some typos. Please ignore those, I assure you spellings are not an issue here.

In checkeligibility() method if the customer is eligible then I show an eligible section on the page. If the eligible message is there then I show the message too, or else, no. If the customer is not eligible, I do not show the eligible section on the page.

Sometimes, although very rarely, I noticed in 1 out of 20 times, the customer is eligible but my page does not show the eligible section.

There are few mistakes I noticed outright:

1. DataType should be 'JSON' if we are expecting result as JSON from the server.
2. We should have been using AJAX.success() method, instead of AJAX.complete(). That way we will have access to the 'data' object.
3. JSONWriter.write(response.getWriter(), values, 2) in the Java file is not right. We should have been converting the 'values' object to the JSON.

Can anyone please help what could be going wrong? Why is my eligible section not appearing that one time on the page even though the customer is eligible?

Comment: I know nothing about JSP, so that code doesn't help (if you want help with that, you should probably add the appropriate tag(s), but I can tell you that the call to `eval` is not recommended, and I don't know why you'd do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`, since that's practically a no-op. Probably best just to change the `dataType` to `'json'` and do a console.log of what comes back from the `success` call, as that should already have been parsed due to the change in `dataType`...

Comment: Why do you have `dataType: 'html'` when the controller is obviously returning JSON, not HTML.